# How to integrate Jmeter with mocha unit testing?

Tags: javascript, jmeter, mocha.js, performance-testing, load-testing

I've written a simple uint test by Mocha Library.

```
describe("simple test", async() =>{

     it("first test" , async()=>{

        assert.equal( 1 , 1);
     })
})
```

Now I need to perform it by JMeter. But I did not find any source for this.

Is it possible to perform the Mocha testing by JMeter or not?

If yes, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [JMeter project main page](https://jmeter.apache.org/):

> The Apache JMeter™ application is open source software, a **100% pure Java application** designed to load test functional behavior and measure performance. It was originally designed for testing Web Applications but has since expanded to other test functions.

Although JMeter supports JavaScript code execution via [JSR223 Test Elements](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223)

[image]

You won't be able to run a Mocha-based tests because [Nashorn](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/nashorn/introduction.htm) engine is not something compatible with [NodeJS](https://nodejs.org/en/) and you won't be able to use [`load()` function](https://wiki.openjdk.org/display/Nashorn/Nashorn+extensions) as Mocha heavily relies on NodeJS

So the only way to run a Mocha test with JMeter is calling `mocha` binary from your node_modules folder using [OS Process Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-external-commands-and-programs-locally-and-remotely-jmeter)

Comment: thanks, seems to be a problem with the link